# Another domain or another view for mobile divece?

Tags: php, mobile

After detecting, that device is mobile, which way is better, redirect another domain

```
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if($detect->isMobile())
{
    header('Location: http://m.site.com/');
    exit;
}
```

or just load another view (html, js, css, ...)

```
if($detect->isMobile())
{
    $this->load->view('mobile_version_view');
}
else {
    $this->load->view('desktop_version_view');
}
```

It just depends on taste or there is some "deep" difference (advantage /disadvantage
) between those ?

Comment: This is primarily opinionated.

Comment: Many schools of thought on this, my personal take on it is -> If the mobile version delivers different content significantly differently, it maybe benificial to have it on another domain/subdomain. If content is very similar, its fair to use another view... The idea behind this attitude is to maintain accurate search engine listings based on the available material.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same view you just needed to write your logic once and decide at the end what will be the view to render

Answer (score 1):

If there is similar content on mobile/not mobile pages, I'd recommend to use multiple view because it's more SEO friendly and also as Fabio stated - controller logic will be in one place.